# Mapping onedrive files to string for OLEDB to read specific files within drive Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, onedrive

I have a program that reads an excel file that is on my local disk. I need this file to be accessible to other individuals to edit the file and allow the program to execute based on its contents. The way were making this accessible is sharing it via OneDrive. The file is read by a OLEDB Script I wrote that takes the directory of the file to read it and load into temp table on the app. I have been searching online for a solution to this in visual basic but a lot of the solutions are written in c# and its hard for me to translate or understand the logic. Here is an example of the solution in pseudo code:

```vb
If (ONEDRIVE_FILE_DIRECTORY IsNot Nothing) Then
    ' STORE FILE FROM ONE DRIVE INTO LOCAL_FILE_DIRECTORY
End If

Dim strConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="LOCAL_FILE_DIRECTORY";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"

Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.TableName = "Results"
dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("LOC_ID", GetType(String)),
                                      New DataColumn("EMAIL", GetType(String)),
                                      New DataColumn("INTERVAL", GetType(String)),
                                      New DataColumn("PASSWORD", GetType(String))
                                      })

Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT [LOC_ID], [EMAIL], [INTERVAL], [PASSWORD] FROM [Report$] WHERE [LOC_ID] <> ''"

Try
    connection.Open()

    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, connection)
        Adp.Fill(dt)
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    LogMessage(ex.ToString, "Error message in """ & strApplicationName & """ job on " & strComputerName & " by: " & strUsername)
    SendEmailErrorMessage(ex.ToString)
Finally
    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        connection.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with an explanation of exactly how the above code isn’t meeting your expectations.  Are you getting exceptions(details if so) or just plain doing the unexpected.

Comment: And in my opinion at least,  excel documents in OneDrive would probably be one of the last options I would consider for sharing data for your app

Comment: The issue isnt the oledb reading excel file its retrieving file from onedrive.

Comment: Guessing there isn't any exception, just plain not working.  Just as an experiment, if you save your excel file to a local folder rather than onedrive, does it work as expected?  Will mean you can eliminate one potential cause of problems

Comment: This is unlikely to work, as Excel via OleDb isn't good at sharing. It's only a matter of time until you have two people needing to use the file too close together and it becomes corrupted. At that point, your data is just gone.

Comment: Copy it to a local Temp directory i.e. Path.GetTempPath then read from it as you normally would

Comment: OneDrive downloads a local copy for the local PC to use then synchronises in background. If two users access the files at the same time, each will update their own version and then OneDrive is likely to throw Sync errors.  I'd suggested finding another way of sharing the Excel file, or better still don't use Excel for this.